# time the output of each tail entry

Tags: bash, time, tail

My goal is to calculate the time (in nanoseconds) between **new** entries in a log file using bash for a period of time\amount of entries - whichever comes first. The best I can achieve is:

```
tail -f logfile | while read line; do echo $(date -u "%H %M $S $N"); done;
```

any ideas please?

Comment: If you require nanosecond precision you probably aren't going to get it using the filesystem.  The latencies involved in the file operations will far exceed the nanosecond or microsecond granularity in most cases, unless you're on very exotic hardware and have an exotic kernel.  If you require nanosecond granularity, you should get the application creating the logfile to log timestamps using that granularity.  That's what we do in the finance world (where nanoseconds matter).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Nanoseconds were specified because it will provide more reliable data but exact precision is not necessary.